# replacing values in the table

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables. I need to replace the values in the second table with the value from the first table, provided that the data in col1, col2 are equal, and in col3 table two the value is less by one than in col3 table 1.

table1:

| Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 111 |
| 5 | 7 | 6 | 222 |

table2:

| Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 333 |
| 5 | 7 | 40 | 444 |

result table2:

| Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 111 |
| 5 | 7 | 40 | 444 |

I tried to correlate for equality ( table1.Column1 == table2.Column1 and
table1.Column2 == table2.Column2 and table1.Column3 == table2.Column2 - 1) I tried using iloc, but it works for a long time on a large amount of data.
how can this be done optimally?
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) :

```
asof = pd.merge_asof(
        df2.sort_values(by="Column 3"), df1.sort_values(by="Column 3"),
        by=["Column1", "Column 2"], on="Column 3", tolerance=1,
        direction="backward", allow_exact_matches=False, suffixes=("_", "")
)

df2["result"] = asof["result"].fillna(df2["result"], downcast="infer")
```

Output :

```
print(df2)

   Column1  Column 2  Column 3  result
0        1         4         4     111
1        5         7        40     444
```

Comment: Nice point `tolerance=1` Be explicit with `direction='backward'` (default)

Comment: I think that's my first ever robust (*I hope*) `asof` answer ;)

Comment: I don't see any exception :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` after subtract 1 to the third column:

```
df2['result'] = (df2.assign(**{'Column 3': df2['Column 3'].sub(1)})
                    .merge(df1, on=['Column1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'], 
                                how='left', suffixes=(None, '_new'))['result_new']
                    .fillna(df2['result'], downcast='infer'))
print(df2)

# Output
   Column1  Column 2  Column 3  result
0        1         4         4     111
1        5         7        40     444
```